# Using custom database in MVC 3 for user login/registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

Okay so I have a `MVC project` that auto generates an `AccountController AcountModel` and the associated views.
I created a database with 3 tables using the model first approach, and generated all the `controllers/views` for all the `CRUD` operations.

The database contains a user table with a user `id`, `email` and `password`.

How can I use this user table with the auto generated `AccountController` for user login and registration?

Comment: There is no way to auto generate `AccountController`, just for CRUD operations. You have to implement by yourself.

Comment: what do you mean by auto generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you registration process only , refering which you can build your login/registration with custom database.

**Models:**
You will add your custommodel to the `AccountModels.cs`, So it will have following details:

```
 public class ChangePasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogOnModel
    {

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }


    public class userDetailModel
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        public string comapny { get; set; }
        public int zip { get; set; }
    }
```

**Context:**
You will add custom context to the `Models` as below:

```
public class userDetailsDBContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<userDetailModel> details { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller:**
Now we will modify our `AccountController` for registration as below:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private userDetailsDBContext db = new userDetailsDBContext();
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(userDetailModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    var newuser = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
                    model.UserId =(Guid)newuser.ProviderUserKey;
                    db.details.Add(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);

        } 
}
```

**EDIT web.config:**
 Finally, you will have to add the new context to the connectionstrings as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MembershipSample-20121105163515;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MembershipSample-20121105163515.mdf" />
    <add name="userDetailsDBContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MembershipSample-20121105163515;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MembershipSample-20121105163515.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

You can change the database name to whatever you want and put it as your convenience but put the path here correctly.

Hope you have got the idea now...

Comment: You will have to modify the AccountController a bit like I have done to work for your own custom tables and database...

Answer (score 0):

I think waht you need is to create custom membership provider. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers) code project article will give you aplace to start.